# How to change frame rect when received a notification from NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I have a view with a button to take an image from camera. When I press the capture button it'll redirect to another view controller. Once I take a photo, the view is pop to the previous view controller. When popping the view I also send a notification to the 1st view controller with the taken image. When the image is receive I tried to change the frame of view `setFrame` method. But the frame didn't get update. What I tried was,

```
- (void) onReceiveImage:(NSNotification *) notification{
     if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"ImageCapturedNotification"]) {
         [self.postTxtView resignFirstResponder];
        NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
        UIImage *image = (UIImage*)userInfo[@"image"];
        [self.postLandImageView setImage:image];
        // in here i want to change the view frame
    }
}
```

To change the frame I did,

```
self.bottomView.frame = CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-self.bottomView.frame.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-self.bottomView.frame.size.height, self.bottomView.frame.size.width, self.bottomView.frame.size.height);
```

This is not working. Please help me tho get this done. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using storyboard/nib & constraints?

Comment: yes. Auto layout and size classes

Comment: Then you need to manipulate the constraints, not the frame.  You can create an IBOutlet reference to the view's top constraint and then modify it's `constant` property.  You can even animate this change

Comment: It works. Thanks. Is there a way to hide the keyboard when received the notification. I tired to resign the first responder inside the `onReceiveImage`. But it's not hiding the keyboard. Now the bottom view frame is updating well

Comment: You are probably resigning the responder from an object that isn't the current responder.  Try http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/01/the-easy-way-to-dismiss-the-ios-keyboard/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you are executing your code on main thread.

> For the most part, use UIKit classes only from your app’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your app’s user interface in any way.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Do any setup on main queue
    });
```

If you are excuting your code on main thread,can you provide a sample demo?

Comment: This worked. `resignFirstResponder` should be called in the main queue. Thank you.